# Mule: Unable to pass Error Status to calling API

Tags: exception, mule

I am trying to capture error status from one API & and send it to the calling API. In my downstream API I have the following catch exception strategy:

```
<catch-exception-strategy>
      <set-payload value= "500" />
      <logger message="***BACKEND API: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

   </catch-exception-strategy>
```

In my calling API I have the following:

```
 <http:request config-ref="downstream API "  path="/downstream/{id}" method="POST " doc:name="Generate "/>
            <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
      <logger message="PAYLOAD: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

However I am able to print the payload in the downstream API but not in the calling API. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If your API throw http.status == 500, it should trigger this condition

```
<choice-exception-strategy doc:name="Choice Exception Strategy">
      <catch-exception-strategy when="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.status' == 500]" doc:name="Error 500">
            <set-payload value= "500" />
            <logger message="***BACKEND API: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
      </catch-exception-strategy>
</choice-exception-strategy>
```

I you didn't add any condition, it should be the default catch exception

everything should work properly.